# BufferedReader prepends input

Tags: java, sockets, telnet, putty, bufferedreader

I am trying to read from a Socket using BufferedReader as follows

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
        }
```

I input a string, say "AUTH", I am getting the value of `line` variable as ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿýAUTH

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe you'd to use a Telnet client:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208993/odd-behavior-when-connecting-to-my-program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That just means the extra data is in the socket for whatever reason. My *guess* is that you're using telnet to connect to the server, and that's the [telnet protocol negotiation](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html).

Java won't add extra data to what's genuinely there.

Comment: Yes i am using telnet (Putty)

Comment: I agree, try with [netcat](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Netcat) instead of telnet. With Putty, under the hostname, there is connection type, use "raw" rather than "telnet".

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader.readLine()` is for input that consists of "lines" make sure that you are providing input correctly. Alternatively, you can define your own terminator and then read input character by character using `BufferedReader.read()` (use a while loop if you don't know the length of input like `while (in.read()!=-1)` or something like this).

Answer (score 0):

> bufferedReader prepends input

No it doesn't. Something is writing extra input that you aren't expecting. In this case, Telnet. Telnet is a protocol that includes more than just lines of text.