# Java BufferedReader returning weird characters

Tags: java, character, bufferedreader

When I run this program, I enter the username as `"dcole"` and the password `"test"` but when I enter them they return with `"ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿýdcole"` and `"ÿþÿþ ÿþÿþ'ÿütest"`.  Here's the code:

```
clientoutput.write("Please enter your username: ".getBytes("UTF-8"));
clientoutput.flush();

String username = clientinput.readLine();
out("Client " + clientip + " logged in as " + username);

String askforpass = "Please enter the password for " + username + ": ";
clientoutput.write(askforpass.getBytes());
clientoutput.flush();

String password = clientinput.readLine();

out(password);
```

Console:

```
Client connected with the IP /127.0.0.1
Client /127.0.0.1 logged in as ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿýdcole ÿþÿþ ÿþÿþ'ÿütest
```

Comment: Where do you create your `BufferedReader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input stream was pure UTF-8, then "dcole" and "test" would be unlikely to be garbled.  (They would be fine if you used Latin-1 or ASCII to decode the bytes, and many other charsets as well.)  Indeed you are seeing the expected characters, but with extra rubbish in front of it.

I suspect that the client is actually preceding the username and password with some extra bytes.  In other words, it is not sending simple text - it is sending messages in some protocol that you haven't described.

In fact, I think that this SO Question might explain your problem:  [Odd Behavior when Connecting to my Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208993/odd-behavior-when-connecting-to-my-program)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a BufferedReader with a wrong charset.

Look at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), when you instance new InputStreamReader you can define the charset.

Comment: Now it comes up with "Client connected with the IP /127.0.0.1
Client /127.0.0.1 logged in as ???? ????'??????dcole
test
"

Comment: You have to set right charset for input stream and output stream too. If you set the right charset on output you don't need to do this `"Please enter your username: ".getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Comment: These are my buffered readers: `    BufferedReader clientinput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
    BufferedOutputStream clientoutput = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());`

Comment: Try using `PrintWriter.print` to output data and init it with "UTF-8" charset.